# WCF service performance

Tags: .net, wcf, service

We have a next situation:

1. Scenario 1

   `WCF` service is hosted on *Server #1*.
   Client application, which is able to bring up multiple threads, each thread has its own data set its working with, each thread calls `WCF` service sending record by record for processing. This Client application is hosted on the same *Server #1*. The performance is great let’s say 100 tps easy with 20 workers.
2. Scenario 2

   `WCF` service is hosted on *Server #1*. Client application is hosted on *Server#2*
   The performance drops down from 100 tps to 10 tps.

Hardware of *Server#1* and *Server#2* are identical.
Both servers have `Windows Server 2008 R2`.
There are no network issues like lost pockets or anything like that, network is fine.
Basic `HTTP Binding` is used.
In both scenarios client calls service by full `URI`.

Any idea why performance drops so much in scenario 2?

Thank you

As a response to some questions below:

It doesn't really meeter what client does, its an application that is able to raise lets say 25 threads, each thread is a client for a service with its own initialized client. Here is a binding settings:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
                <binding 
                    name="basicHttp" 
                    closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                    openTimeout="00:10:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                    sendTimeout="00:10:00"                     
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="true"                     
                    maxBufferSize="65536" 
                    maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" 
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" 
                    textEncoding="utf-8" 
                    transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                   <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="81920"    maxArrayLength="163840"
                    maxBytesPerRead="409600" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

But i have tried all possible combinations. Also i have to mention that we have another client developed in Java utilizing the same service through the network using Basic HTTP binding and having no issues with performance.

Comment: My guess would be now you're adding a network conection in to the mix. Do you happen to use net tcp or standard wsHttpBinding? (ws requires more overhead as it involved more markup/metadata).

Comment: Have you tested the network latency?

Comment: Brad, that's one of the planned steps to try NET TCP binding.

Comment: Jeff, yes network is perfectly fine.

Comment: Finally i had time to set up netTcpBinding. With netTcpBinding used the performance is back to normal i have 100 tps with no issues, but this still doesn't answer the main question why there is such a drop in performance with Basic HTTP binding. Another thing is that we have a client written in Java, accessing the same Basic HTTP binding through the network and having no issues with performance 100 tps easy.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the slowdown is caused by necessity to transfer data from server to client.  Try to set the binding's [TransferMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx) to the Streamed value.  I have a situation when large object had to be passed to the client and this setting helped me significantly...

Comment: Tried this the same situation no changes